# remove class to sibling of elemnt jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Jquery function, with a filter that adds a class named `selected` to the filter by click and shows all that data filter tags of the selected filter.

I want to define that if the sibling of the chosen element has a class named `selected`, that class needs to be removed from the rest and has to be added to only the selected element.

**Function Script**

```
 (function ($) {

"use strict";

$.fn.filter = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        nav: '[data-filter]' //
    }

    var $this = this,
        settings = $.extend(defaults, options),
        $target = $(settings.target),
        selected = [];

    return this.each( function() {

        var $element = $(this);

        $(settings.nav).each( function() {

            $(this).click( function(event) {

                // add selected class
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');

                // manipulate selected terms array
                if ($.inArray($(this).data('filter'), selected) < 0 ) {
                    selected.push($(this).data('filter'));
                } else {
                    var index = $.inArray($(this).data('filter'), selected);
                    selected.splice(index, 1);
                }

                // show/hide elements
                $element.find('[data-filter-tags]').each( function() {

                    var terms = $(this).data('filter-tags').split(','),
                        show = null;

                    for (var i=0;i<selected.length;i++) {
                        show = ($.inArray(selected[i], terms) >= 0 && show !== false);
                    }

                    if (show || selected.length == 0) {
                        $(this).fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $(this).fadeOut();
                    }
                });

                event.preventDefault();

            });

        });

    });

};

  }(jQuery));
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="tags">
  <div id="cities" data-activeclass="selected">
<a href="#" class="city" data-filter="telaviv">תל אביב</a>
<a href="#" class="city"   data-filter="ramatgan">רמת גן</a>
    <a href="#" id="city"  data-filter="city">הכל</a>
    <div>
</br>
<a href="#" data-filter="full">משרה מלאה    </a>
<a href="#" data-filter="part">משרה חלקית</a>
        <a href="#" data-filter="time">הכל</a>
</br>
  <a href="#" data-filter="sec">מזכירות</a>
       <a href="#" data-filter="op">הפעלה</a>
                <a href="#" data-filter="kind">הכל</a>
       </br>
   </nav>
     <div id="filter">
     <div class="block" style="background: green" data-filter- 
    tags="time,kind,city,telaviv,full,sec">תל אביב משרה מלאה מזכירות</div>
   <div class="block" style="background: blue" data-filter- 
  tags="time,kind,city,ramatgan,full,sec">רמת גן מלאה מזכירות</div>
<div class="block" style="background: blue" data-filter- 
  tags="time,kind,city,ramatgan,part,op">רמת גן חלקית הפעלה</div>
    <div class="block" style="background: blue" data-filter- 
     tags="time,kind,city,telaviv,full,op">תל אביב מלאה הפעלה</div>
            <div class="block" style="background: blue" data-filter- 
  tags="time,kind,city,ramatgan,part,sec">רמת גן חלקית מזכירות</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You've done a really good job on what looks like your second question. Nice one! FWIW, it's usually best to trim things down a bit more to create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to define that if the sibling of the choosen elemnts has class named
>   "selected" remove the class from them and add it only to the selected element.

If clicking the element selects it and deselects all of its siblings, then in your `click` handler:

```
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

Simplified live example:

```js
$("[data-filter]").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
[data-filter] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-filter="1">one</span>
  <span data-filter="2">two</span>
  <span data-filter="3">three</span>
  <span data-filter="4">four</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If clicking the element *toggles* it, we want `toggleClass` (which you have) but the rest is the same:

```
$(this).toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

...since the `.siblings().removeClass("selected");` part just won't do anything if the current element was the one that was selected.

Simplified live example:

```js
$("[data-filter]").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
[data-filter] {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-filter="1">one</span>
  <span data-filter="2">two</span>
  <span data-filter="3">three</span>
  <span data-filter="4">four</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. it's switching the selected class on click as I wanted but it doesn't show the data filter tags of the element with the selected class now

Comment: @rovn - You'll have to update the question with that [mcve] I mentioned. :-) Along with a clear statement of what you want to happen with the clicks.